# How can I modify the labels using Gmail Query

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail-api

Is there any way to modify the label using gmail query (GTLQueryGmail).
I had gone through the api documentations the api which perform this is:-  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

I want this to be done through gmail Query in iOS

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what GTL Query is specifically, I imagine some iOS client object.  the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify" you mention is just the auth scope name you need in your oauth2 token in to be allowed to make the call (there are a few that'll work for modifying labels actually).

What you want to do is use the message modify() operation, I don't know what that translates to in iOS but here are docs on it:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify

Or to change labels on all messages in a thread, use thread modify:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify