# Issues with modifying labels on a message

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

**Context:** Need to modify messages and remove the label (remove *Unread* label) in Gmail Inbox using GMAIL API

**Issue:** Inbox contains several *Unread* emails, but when the program executes, it removes the *Unread* label only for a few of them.

**Observation:** There is no specific pattern in the emails which are excluded from being modified (removal of *Unread* label). In debug mode, I notice that all *Unread* emails are selected, but when it reaches the code section below it does not modify in some cases. No matter how many times I re-run the program those emails which are excluded in the first run does not get modified & remains as *Unread* in Inbox

```
Message message = service.users().messages().modify(userId, messageId, mods).execute();
```

**Research:** I am using the same code provided in [Link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) . I also referred to a few threads in this forum, but none of them address this specific issue (eg: [Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694628/how-to-create-and-access-gmail-account-details-using-java-apis/39722551#39722551), [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311764/how-can-i-modify-the-labels-using-gmail-query))

Hope the issue faced is clear. If anyone has faced this peculiar issue, can you kindly throw light on what I need to do to fix this issue.

**Added:** Code - [Link](https://pastebin.com/6PdM19xP)

Comment: Are you trying to delete a system label (unread) from gmail. or are you simply trying to remove the unread tag from a message?

Comment: @DaImTo I am trying to remove the Unread Label from the mail. If you refer to the code in the link provided in my query, the setRemoveLabelIds(labelsToRemove) is what helps in this case. What is perplexing is it works for some emails, while it does not for few others.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  your code only shows how modify a single message it does not show how you are trying to modify a group of messages nor does it show what you are trying to modify it with.

Comment: @DaImTo have updated my query with the code which you can use for checking.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code not a link to your code.